How to change visibility for some TreeDataGrid rows?
I want to make a custom filter for my TreeDataGrid (flat). My model LogLine have reactive property IsVisible, but all my attempts to add binding to model from TreeDataGridRow style are useless.
<TreeDataGrid.Styles>
   <Style Selector="TreeDataGridRow"
      x:DataType="model:LogLine">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="{Binding $self.((model:LogLine)DataContext).IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </Style>
</TreeDataGrid.Styles> 

P.S. Inspector showing correct DataContext in TreeDataGridRow...
NET 8
Avalonia 11.1.3 (latest)
TreeDataGrid 11.0.10 (latest)
I'm trying bindings, template bindings, but it dosn't work

I expected mine TreeDataGrid and TreeDataGridRow.IsVisible has set with LocalValue priority. I guess it is set by TreeDataGridRowPresenter. Means you can't simply change its value from style selector.

Here is an opened filter feature request. As workaround you can recreate HierarchicalTreeDataGridSource instance when filter is changed, using filtered IEnumerable as constructor parameter, e.g. with linq .Where(o => o.IsVisible).

You will not be able to set TreeDataGridRow.IsVisible from Selector, because (as of now) it is set to true with LocalValue priority. In the future pay attention to "Priority" column in Avalonia inspector.
You can set the value with the help of attached behavior.
Here is a solution with behavior:
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Behaviors;

public class TreeDataGridBehavior : AvaloniaObject
{
    public static readonly AttachedProperty<bool> IsRowVisibleProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.RegisterAttached<TreeDataGridBehavior, bool>(
            "IsRowVisible", typeof(TreeDataGridBehavior));

    public static void SetIsRowVisible(AvaloniaObject element, bool value) =>
        element.SetValue(IsRowVisibleProperty, value);
    public static bool GetIsRowVisible(AvaloniaObject element) =>
        element.GetValue(IsRowVisibleProperty);

    static TreeDataGridBehavior()
    {
        IsRowVisibleProperty.Changed.AddClassHandler<TreeDataGridRow, bool>(
            (row, e) => row.IsVisible = e.NewValue == true);
    }
}

And xaml (define on root element xmlns:bb="clr-namespace:Behaviors"):
<TreeDataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="TreeDataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="bb:TreeDataGridBehavior.IsRowVisible"
                Value="{ReflectionBinding IsVisible}"/>
    </Style>
</TreeDataGrid.Styles>


This seems to break all kinds of stuff with the hierarchy. Attempting to click in the tree or on expanders after visually hiding elements throws exceptions.
